If $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ then $G$ is abelian.
I want to show the following two statements:
a) Let $G$ be a group such that $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ then $G$ is abelian.
For part a) I have the following facts "If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian." and also know that "Finitely generated subgroups of $\mathbb Q$ is cyclic."
I have something like $G/Z(G) \cong R \le \mathbb Q$. If $R$ is finitely generated then we are done. What if $R$ is not finitely generated?

Hint: assume for contradiction that some $a, b \in G$ don't commute, and consider $H = \left< a, b \right> \leqslant G$.
PS It is also not hard to unpack the reasoning so that it does not use any external facts. From the assumption we get a group homomorphism $\varphi : G \to \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\ker \varphi = Z(G)$. Now take any $a, b \in G$. We will show that $ab = ba$. The subgroup
$$\varphi[ \left< a, b \right> ] = \left< \varphi(a), \varphi(b) \right> \leqslant \mathbb{Q}$$
is cyclic, so we can find $c \in \left< a, b \right>$ and $i, j \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\varphi(a) = i \cdot \varphi(c)$ and $\varphi(b) = j \cdot \varphi(c)$. It follows that $a \equiv c^i \pmod{Z(G)}$ and $b \equiv c^j \pmod{Z(G)}$ and hence $ab = ba$.

The same argument shows more generally that if $G/Z(G)$ is locally cyclic (i.e., every finitely generated subgroup is cyclic), then $G$ must be abelian. Every subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ is locally cyclic.
